# Seaborn pairplot kde diagonal default behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn, kernel-density

When using seaborn’s pairplot, I use the hue parameter which defaults diag_kind to 'kde'.

If I have 3 levels of “hues” or levels in my data, do the areas under each of the kde curves equal 1 (similar to matplotlib stacked=False)? Or is it that the areas under all 3 curves combined equal 1 (similar to matplotlib stacked=True)?

I’m trying to visualize the distribution of the 3 levels separately, so I’m hoping the area under each of the curves is equal to 1. If this is not the default behavior, is there a way to make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is wrong, its result will not produce individually normalized densities. The correct way to do this is by supplying a `diag_kws` argument:

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(penguins, diag_kind="kde", hue="species", diag_kws=dict(common_norm=False))
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc3RN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want.

You can run

```
sns.pairplot(your_dataset, palette="hls", diag_kind="kde", hue="column_name_in_your_dataset" )
```

which would use one selected column's values to add an extra level to your visualisation.